# Exporting a KHR_materials_unlit material with alpha

Tags: gltf, shadeless

I need to export a glTF model with a material that uses the [`KHR_materials_unlit` extension](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/main/extensions/2.0/Khronos/KHR_materials_unlit/README.md). This is a simple faked shadow, and so I need the material to use an image with an alpha texture on it.

The 2.8 manual suggested to use a Background material to get `KHR_materials_unlit`, but that does not support alpha:
[image: screenshot of shader graph editor, showing the Background node has only a Color input]

The latest manual has a more complicated suggestion, but again the solution has no mechanism to support alpha:

> To export an unlit material, mix in a camera ray, and avoid using the Principled BSDF node. [image]

Comment: For reference, [this](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/pull/1209#issuecomment-693700508) is what the exporter expects.

Comment: @scurest Thanks! That's...frustratingly cumbersome. I hope future Blender can improve on this to make it simpler to turn off shading without creating complex shader graphs for each material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work and is pretty simple, using a Mix Shader surface for the material, with the Fac set to the alpha of the image, the first Shader set to a Transparent BSDF, and the second Shader set to the color of the image:
[image: screenshot of the Shader Graph Editor showing what is described above]

This is similar to, but simpler than, what Blender creates if you hand-edit a glTF file to use `KHR_materials_unlit` with an alpha material and then import that glTF into Blender:
[image: complex shader set up by Blender for simple unlit texture]